# Custom AuthorizeAttribute OnAuthorizationAsync Function

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I'm trying to make my own custom `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute`. Everything was working until I needed to run some `async` function inside of the overridden `OnAuthorization`function.

I found the `OnAuthorizationAsync` method and I use that, however still having issues running an `async` method. I need to ensure that a header attached to the `HttpActionContext` is in the db.

```
    public override Task OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> values;
        if (actionContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValues("Authentication", out values))
        {
            var token = new Token() { TokenString = values.First() };
            if (await _tg.ValidateToken(token))
            {
                return base.OnAuthorizationAsync(actionContext, cancellationToken);
            }
        }

        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
    }
```

---

`_tg.ValidateToken(token)` is an `async` method that returns a bool.  If I try to `await` it and make `OnAuthorizationAsync` an `async` method I then apparently cant return a Task:

> Since OnAuthorizeAsync is an `async` method that returns 'Task', a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression.

Is there a way you can see out of this mess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @sellotape's answer:

```
public async override Task OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    IEnumerable<string> values;
    if (actionContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValues("Authentication", out values))
    {
        var token = new Token() { TokenString = values.First() };
        if (await _tg.ValidateToken(token))
        {
            return await base.OnAuthorizationAsync(actionContext, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
    await base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
}
```

Comment: This is not complete. You need to `await base.OnAuthorizationAsync`, not return it. don't just pass the `Task`.

Answer (score 4):

Because you use `await`, you need to add the `async` modifier to the method's declaration. Then change the `return` you have there to `await`. The compiler will do the rest - i.e. returning the `Task` for you.

Comment: @Nick H, should mark this answer as valid if it works for you